# problem opening sitecollection locally sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a sitecollection and in AAM I have made following settings for 
my sitecollection at port 80,name of sitecollection is VSMOSS

```
http://VSMOSS          default(zone)     http://vsmos.Ttl.com
http://vsmoss.Ttl.com  default(zone)     http://vsmoss.Ttl.com
http://vsmoss.com      default(zone)     http://vsmoss.Ttl.com
```

But the problem is when I open this side locally its asking for login name and password and its not letting me in........and when I try to open it outside its opening........anyone knows what could be the problem...

Comment: I tried this ...But still its not working.
May be I am doing something wrong.. in regedit I followed the second method according to article 896861 and in modify data I typed
http://vsmoss.Ttl.com but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Solution for being unable to sign-in to the Shared Services administration screens](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/05/solution-for-being-unable-to-sign-in-to.html)

Comment: Not sure he's asking about the admin screens, but pretty ambiguous so who knows.

Comment: Same problem, the name of the article just happens to mention Central Admin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific in your question to get real help.

*"But the problem is when I open this side locally its asking for login name and password and its not letting me in........and when I try to open it outside its opening"*

What exactly does that mean?

- Does it mean when you try an open
  using netbios name of http://VSMOSS
  its failing but it is working using
  http://vsmoss.Ttl.com?
- Does it mean when you try and browse
  to site using a browser runnin on the
  server its failing but its working
  when using a browser running on
  anothe computer.

If its the latter then the problem is probably the Local Loopack check :-

[DisableLoopbackCheck & SharePoint:
   What every admin and developer should
   know.](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Comment: sorry for not being clear Ryan...yah its the latter one...let me check the link you gave...Thanks...

Comment: Ryan I tried this and put still I am not able to get it ...any idea what i m doing wrong..

Comment: You've marked an answer as correct so I assume you've got it working now?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to make sure DisableLoopBackCheck is configured properly.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 for more information.